# How do I get a listing of the contents of a Document Library?

Tags: development, document-library, infopath, web-services

Sorry for the simple question.

I have a Form Library whose directory listing I need to access from an InfoPath form containing custom code. I don't need the contents of any of the files, just the filename of the newest document in the library. What service/library can I use that will help grab this information?

I'm writing in C#

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems%28v=office.12%29.aspx) webservice. You could experiment with [Caml Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) in order to get your query right to return the newest document.

Answer (score 1):

I found out I can just add a data connection to a Form Library and access the data source through XPath tools. That way you don't even need SharePoint connection libraries. (c: